# Modifying An Array Element From a Helm Library Chart

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a library chart that's shared among multiple deployments. Say I have a segment like so:

```
{{- define "mylibchart.template.tpl" -}}
...
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 300
  containers:
    - image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
      name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 300
...
{{- end -}}
{{- define "mylibchart.template" -}}
{{- include "mylibchart.util.merge" (append . "mylibchart.template.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}}
```

When implementing the library chart, I'm able to directly override elements outside an array:

```
{{- include "mylibchart.template" (list . "foobar.deployment") -}}
{{- define "foobar.deployment" -}}
kind: Pod
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 333
{{- end -}}
```

But the following is **illegal**, because containers is an array.

```
{{- include "mylibchart.template" (list . "foobar.deployment") -}}
{{- define "foobar.deployment" -}}
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 333
{{- end -}}
```

I only have 1 container in my library. Is there a way, in the implementing file, to refer to that one listed container, and add to/modify its values? I'm aware you can use helm values, but in my use case there are some values that only appear once or twice, so the library chart starts to get filled with scaffolding that only gets used by 1 or two services.

This can be worked around, but a direct solution would be nice.

Comment: What is `mylibchart.template`?  I'm not clear what you mean by "modify" or "override" here; both of these templates appear to write out fragments of YAML that will be emitted when they run, and nothing is obviously trying to mutate data structures.

Comment: the first code block is a fragment of mylibchart.template